# How to draw a transparent image using WinAPI ImageList_DrawIndirect?

Tags: image, winapi, transparency, draw, imagelist

I need to draw a 32-bit image from a native API imagelist with the specified level of transparency, but I can't do that. I'm using the `ImageList_DrawIndirect` call and the `ILS_ALPHA` image state in the `IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS` structure passed to `ImageList_DrawIndirect`, but it seems it doesn't work as expected. ComCtl of v6 is "attached" to my app so it's not the reason of the problem.

How to do that?

My code looks like this:

```
Dim idp As IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS

idp.cbSize = Len(idp)
idp.himl = m_hIml
idp.hdcDst = hdc
idp.rgbBk = -1
idp.x = xPixels
idp.y = yPixels
idp.i = 0
idp.fState = ILS_ALPHA
idp.Frame = 128

ImageList_DrawIndirect(idp)
```

It's VB6, but it doesn't matter - in fact, we are working only with pure WinAPI at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code works perfectly for me in my app. By that I mean that I have the same code in my app, with the sole exception that I am not setting `rgbBk`.

My guess is that somehow the images in your image list have lost their alpha channel.

I'm surprised to see that you set `rgbBk` because I believe it has no effect for images with alpha.

Comment: Maybe, the problem is really in the images? Do we need to use a special procedure to prepare them? Or any 32-bit icon (.ico) can be used this way?

Comment: The issue could be in either the image or possible the image list. The image list needs to be created with the ILC_COLOR32 flag. How are you adding icons to the image list?

Comment: David, thanks a lot for your brilliant answer. Maybe, it was evident for you but not for me :). Removing idp.rgbBk = -1 helped to solve the prob. I do not know why I missed that when I tried it myself.

Comment: David, stop - not so fast :)!

Comment: It works in Win7 but does not work in WinXP!!! I just see semitransparent rectangles with the specified transparency level instead of real images. What it could be?

Comment: @wisekat are you still doing this inside your app, or have you extracted it into a separate, small, test app?

Comment: yes, i'm doing this even in two apps - one (main) where I develop an ActiveX that uses this functionality, and the other app is a simple standalone exe.

Comment: @wisekat It will take a little while before I can reach a machine with XP and try it out. I'll report back!

Comment: @wisekat I'm getting the grey squares too in XP. My guess is that XP does not support ILS_ALPHA.

Comment: Wonderfull :(
Have any thoughts how the transparency effect can be implemented and work at least in WinXP/Vista/Win7?

Comment: @wisekat Why do you want to do that anyway? I'd guess you are looking at the [AlphaBlend()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183353(VS.85).aspx) API.

Comment: Actually, before you give up on it, you could post another more direct Q here. Ask, "Does anybody know if ImageList_DrawIndirect with fState = ILS_ALPHA works on XP? It works on 7, but on XP the transparent regions of the icon are grey." I would make no mention of VB and if you have to include code, include C++ code. Use the windows and winapi tags. VB6 is a turnoff here, very few people still use it so you'll not get too much help.

Comment: No matter whether it is VC or VB as only native WinAPI is used in code.
Thank you for all your efforts! I have just placed a new, more specific question, as you suggested.

Comment: @wisekat I agree it doesn't matter, but if you tag it VB or VB6 you'll miss out on lots of people that could maybe answer.